# How to play combined sound as if emanating from a crowd of sound-producing objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio

Consider that I have 100 instances of a "squeaker" class. Each "squeaker" object is capable of individually emitting a squeak sound. Each squeaker entity uses the same .mp3 resource. When all the squeakers are presented together on screen (for example as little characters), I want them all to squeak at approximately (but not exactly) the same time so that their combined squeaks are heard together as a crowd of squeakers.

Targeting iOS, what approach (and audio/sound framework) do you recommend? Has anyone done this before? Code samples?

Comment: What I'm really hoping for is someone that has actually sought this effect and could share some source or example code.

Comment: A "crowd" will also make slightly different squeaks. You can emulate this by varying the amplitude/speed (see "automatic double tracking"). A better way is probably just to have a pre-recorded "100 squeakers" sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be best to build this like a "laugh track", where you use an audio editor to combine multiple squeaks into one MP3 file, which you then play in a loop (this file could and should be much longer than a single squeak).

By trying to render 100 sounds as separate sound-playing instances of whatever, you'd be running into the same sort of voice and latency problems encountered by developers of software synthesizers.  Maintaining a voice count of 100 with an overall latency of less than 25 milliseconds or so is difficult to do on a modern PC, and much more difficult (or impossible) to do on an iPhone/iPad.

Generally speaking, voice and latency represent a fundamental engineering tradeoff:  it's fairly easy to have a low-latency synthesis engine on a mobile device, but this can only be achieved with a very small number of voices (i.e. distinct concurrent sounds).  Conversely (like my own software synthesis engine), you can have an engine that can handle an effectively infinite number of voices, but with a very high latency (on the order of many seconds).

**Update:**  generating your own sounds programmatically is an excellent idea.  You can do this relatively easily in iPhone using the `AVAudioPlayer` class.  Normally, this class is initialized using its `initWithURL` method, which is used to load audio data from a file.

In your case, you want to instead use the `initWithData` method.  You pass an `NSData` object here, which is basically just a block of bytes.  In this case, you want the block of bytes to be an in-memory WAV file, which will consist of a 44-byte header followed by an array of 2-byte integers, which represents the actual sample data.

You set the values in the header (stuff like sample rate, bits per sample, number of channels etc.) and then calculate the sample values using whatever algorithm you like.  A simple `sin` wave is a good thing to start with, but this will just produce a boring tone.  A more interesting sound (and one that might be close to what you're looking for) is called a "chirp" - this is basically a short sin-wave-based sound, but the frequency of the sin wave changes from high frequency to low frequency during the sound's playback.

Sorry, I have tons of audio code for C# and Java, but nothing yet for the iPhone.  Hopefully what I've added here will help you google for this.  You basically just need to figure out two things:  1) how to use `AVAudioPlayer` using `initWithData`, and the file format of a WAV file.

Comment: Thank you, very good comment. What do you think about using procedurally generated sounds instead of prerecorded sound resources?

Comment: @icnivad: I think it's a good idea. Generating sounds procedurally instead of embedding them in your app as resources will help keep the size of your download small.

Comment: superb info! Any relevant C# or Java code would be incredible as I can experiment. If you have a chirp example I could run in C# it would be very worthwhile.

Comment: I can't find any tutorials on this at all - not even awful ones. I may have to write my first iPhone tutorial, as I know this is really straightforward. My guess is most people that want to do progammatical sound use `AudioQueue`.

Comment: I've posted a related question regarded procedural sound (specifically the chirp you mentioned) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659522/how-to-make-and-play-a-procedurally-generated-chirp-sound

Answer (score 2):

First of all, do not use MP3. The iPhone/iPod/iPad uses hardware accelerated sound decoding for the first instance of a lossy compressed sound/audio-layer. Since iOS (i think) 3.0, one additional lossy compressed sound can be played but that will put substantial load onto the CPU as it is not hardware accelerated. AFAIK that is the limit already for MP3 and AAC.

As a personal favorite, I would suggest using OpenAL in connection with RAW (uncompressed) 16bit audio files. OpenAL is really straight forward, flexible and well documented (outside of Apple's references). You will however hit a limit there as well. From what I remember, OpenAL on the iOS device has a limit of 32 voices being played at the very same time.

Comment: Thank you. I've been considering OpenAL and knowing that I could potentially run up to 32 voices simultaneously would probably achieve something close to the desired effect. I wonder if attempting to use more than 32 voices at once would throw an error or would just quietly not execute those additional voices.

Comment: Or just decompress the MP3 into a memory buffer and play that? I think AVAudioPlayer may do this.